# Trigger open WhatsApp application on mobile browser without asking permission

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, next.js13, whatsapp

I'm working on a Next.js 13 application where a store is shown. The user then goes to certain product detail and can contact the owner of the product via WhatsApp, so far, that's ok. I can use the Universal Link from WhatsApp (`https://wa.me`).

The thing here is that I want to open directly WhatsApp without asking for it. I know it may sounds kind of strange as it's a privacy/security thing, but, I just found a website called [Inmuebles24](https://www.inmuebles24.com/) where you can contact the apartments owner by WhatsApp, in a mobile browser (Safari/Chrome), ALWAYS the WhatsApp application is opened without asking me for permission and that happens in both browsers that I've tested out *Safari* and *Google Chrome* with an iPhone 14.

In my case, I've figured out that sometimes opens without asking for permission and sometimes the prompt is shown.

Before opening the link, I ask for the user a few data (name, email and phone number) once he filled up the form, I get the owner phone number to use it in the WhatsApp link.

```js
const whatsAppLink = 'https://wa.me/REPLACEPHONENUMBER/?text=%C2%A1Hello,%20I%20am%20interested%20in%20your%20product!%20Please%20provide%20me%20with%20more%20information.%20Thank%20you!'

const onSubmitForm = async (data) => {
    try {
        const res = await requestOwnerPhoneNumber(data);
        const phoneNumber = res?.data ?? DEFAULT_WHATSAPP_NUMBER;
        const link = whatsAppLink.replace('REPLACEPHONENUMBER', phoneNumber);
        window.location.href = link;
    } catch (error) {
        errorAlert({
            content: 'Something went wrong, please try again later',
        });
    }
};
```

As you can see, once I have the WhatsApp link, I do a `window.location.href` which I expect, on mobile, open directly WhatsApp without asking for it.

How could I reproduce the same behavior as [Inmuebles24](https://www.inmuebles24.com/)? Any thougths?